# How to get All Microsoftword files using C#

Tags: c#, ms-office

I've opened 4,5 different files and I want to get detail of each file.
detail means file name, fullpath etc.

```
 objWord = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
 for (int i = 0; i < objWord.Windows.Count; i++)
     {
            label.Content = objWord.ActiveDocument.FullName.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;

     }
```

using above lines I'm able to get the detail of current active file detail. how can I get the detail of other files that are not active.

Comment: You're only accessing the `ActiveDocument`, why do you expect it to give you anything but that?  Maybe you should trying accessing the documents by index, otherwise your `for` loop is doing nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're accessing the same `ActiveDocument` on each iteration of your loop (and overwriting the value every time). Try changing the line in your `for` loop to:

```
label.Content += objWord.Windows(i).Document.FullName.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: it just a example .. this line.. actually i want to get all documents detail but each time it returns me same name

Comment: my problem is that each time it returns me detail of active file not the others. I need all files detail. I know i'm overwriting label.content. its just an example.